# How to decode frame sent by GPS Concox AT4

Tags: c#, .net-core, gps

I already have it configured via SMS to the GPS so that it sends me data to a public server through port 10000. I have raised the server with socket from C#

However, when the data arrives, it seems to arrive encrypted

I add 3 examples.

xxST??Xx0IPK
xxST??Xx0IA?
xxST??Xx0IsY

If someone knows how to decrypt what I would appreciate since I need the latitude and longitude

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation of your GPS chip. Do not try to guess.

Comment: there is no technical documentation only the user one.

Comment: Check the datasheet, to see which GPS chip they are using (else look for main brands: there are just few) and check how to request version. Or just listen at boot. I think the first line is often version and model (of the chip). After you get such information, you get a lot of documentation. Or just check the main two manufactures: I think all others uses same or similar format.